Is this union pointer member type punning UB in C?
Given the untyped_sequence and int_sequence below:
typedef struct {
    void* data;       // first item
    size_t size;      // number of items
    size_t item_size; // item byte size
} untyped_sequence;

typedef struct {
    int* data;        // first int
    size_t size;      // number of ints
    size_t item_size; // int byte size
} int_sequence;

QUESTION: Is it UB to put them as two union members, initialize an instance of that union using the int_sequence member, then mutating the int data using the untyped_sequence member?

If yes - why?
If no - why?

GCC, Clang and MSVC give no warnings about this, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything.
Minimal runnable example (https://godbolt.org/z/PT6ahh4qq):
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    void* data;       // first item
    size_t size;      // number of items
    size_t item_size; // item byte size
} untyped_sequence;

typedef struct {
    int* data;        // first int
    size_t size;      // number of ints
    size_t item_size; // int byte size
} int_sequence;

typedef union {
    int_sequence typed;
    untyped_sequence untyped;
} sequence;

void untyped_zero_first(untyped_sequence untyped) {
    memset(untyped.data, 0, untyped.size * untyped.item_size);
}

int main(void) {
    int ints[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    sequence s = {
        .typed.data      = ints,
        .typed.size      = 4,
        .typed.item_size = sizeof(int)
    };
    untyped_zero_first(s.untyped);
    // prints "0, 0, 0, 0" for GCC, Clang, MSVC - but is ut UB?
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", ints[0], ints[1], ints[2], ints[3]);
}


for me in this case, I see no value in that union. void * can be just converted to an int * easily.

@Johann, Since a void * and int * may differ in size, code risks UB.  Consider void * not fully well defined when int * is smaller.

Although such architectures are uncommon, untyped_sequence and int_sequence could differ in size.

@KamilCuk: I agree, as far as the example goes. But this is a minimal example of a much, much bigger scenario where it makes a lot of value.

@chux: Let's assume I'm only interested in platforms where all pointer types are of equal size - do you still see the risk of UB?

@JohannGerell Size is one issue. Even with equal size, the pointer by-passed the int * to/from void * conversion and so might not work.  Yet an unequal size and even needing a conversion that changes pointer bits are quite uncommon in most machines.  You may not notice any undesirable UB.  Yet rather than try to  look for no UB in your code, consider posting the larger goals and seek a no UB solution.

@JohannGerell The tricky part about UB is that compilers use that excuse to make efficient code.  Even if a compilation will emit desired functionality, a new compiler version (or perhaps with more optimizations enabled) may now do undesirable, yet efficient things.  Best to avoid UB.


Is this union pointer member type punning UB in C?

Yes, in that the language spec does not define the behavior (as opposed to explicitly declaring it undefined).
Unlike C++, C does not have a sense of an "active" member of a union. Accessing a different member than was initialized or last stored does not, in and of itself, produce undefined behavior.  Since C17, the behavior is not even implementation-defined.  You can just do it, which involves (as a note in the spec clarifies) reinterpreting the appropriate part of the stored value according to the type of the accessed member.
But in your particular case, that's not enough. C does not require that the size and representation of type void * be the same as the size and representation of type int *.  As far as the spec is concerned, there is no telling, at the point where your example code calls untyped_zero_first(s.untyped), what s.untyped.data points to.  It might even be a trap representation if your implementation's void * representation affords those.
In practice, you're unlikely to run into a modern platform in which different object pointer types in fact do have different size or representation, so your code is likely to work as intended, but C does not guarantee that.

If I understand you correctly, the issue is the possibility of different sized pointer types, right? If so, static asserting that they are indeed same sized would rid the possibility of that type punning issue in this scenario, right?

@JohannGerell Asserting equal size is one good step, yet equivalent pointer representation is not assured - its still UB.

@chux: Interestimg, thanks. LLM summarized it like this: "In summary, while all pointers to scalar types (e.g., int, float, char) have the same representation and alignment requirements, there are exceptions and additional considerations for pointers to structures, arrays, functions, and qualified types."

Which is why, @JohannGerell, you should never ask LLMs such questions.  That answer is not grounded in the C language spec, and I don't think it has historically been true of all C implementations.  Some parts of that response don't even make sense.  Never ask an LLM a question if you are not prepared to evaluate its response.


The pointers and other fields union punning is implementation defined.


Union Type-Punning Exception (C11, Section 6.5.2.3, Paragraph 3):

"A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, to the unit in which it
resides), and vice versa."

"If the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last stored into, the behavior is
implementation-defined."




Using the pointers (it may invoke UB)


Effective Type Rule (C11, Section 6.5, Paragraph 7):
"An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:

a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
a character type."

Strict Aliasing Rule (C11, Section 6.5, Paragraph 7):

"An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: a type compatible with
the effective type of the object..."


Answering in a few words:

union type punning is implementation defined
using the pointers depends on the referenced objects and pointer types. It may invoke undefined behaviour (UB)

Example invoking and not invoking UB assuming assuming the correctness if the implementation.
typedef struct {
    void* data;       // first item
    size_t size;      // number of items
    size_t item_size; // item byte size
} untyped_sequence;

typedef struct {
    int* data;        // first int
    size_t size;      // number of ints
    size_t item_size; // int byte size
} int_sequence;


typedef struct {
    float* data;        // first int
    size_t size;      // number of ints
    size_t item_size; // int byte size
} float_sequence;


typedef union {
    int_sequence typed;
    untyped_sequence untyped;
    float_sequence floatseq;
} sequence;

void untyped_zero_first(untyped_sequence untyped) {
    memset(untyped.data, 0, untyped.size * untyped.item_size);
}

int main(void) {
    int ints[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    //no UB here
    sequence s = 
    {
        .typed.data      = ints,
        .typed.size      = 4,
        .typed.item_size = sizeof(int)
    };
    untyped_zero_first(s.untyped);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", s.typed.data[0], s.typed.data[1], s.typed.data[2], s.typed.data[3]);

    //UB
    printf("%f, %f, %f, %f\n", s.floatseq.data[0], s.floatseq.data[1], s.floatseq.data[2], s.floatseq.data[3]);

}


You quoted the same rule twice under the names "Effective Type Rule' and "Strict Aliasing Rule".

@interjay they are different despite coming the the same pragrapth

How can the same text from exactly the same place in the standard be different from itself?

@KamilCuk the pointer is passed to memset not dereferenced directly (which is not possible for void). memset does not invoke UB in this case as it guaranteed this function to access referenced objects not violating strict-aliasing rules

Interesting DV - any explanation?

Since C17, the spec no longer calls out "the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last stored into" as having implementation-defined behavior.  That procedure unconditionally reads the value of the accessed member.  A note clarifies that this involves reinterpretation of (the appropriate part of) the stored value according to the type of the accessed member.

@JohnBollinger: Tnx, will that change the validity of the above answer?

@JohannGerell, it affects the claim that type punning is implementation-defined (which requires conforming implementations to actually document their behavior in that area).  But in practice, what C17 and later require is the same as what implementations typically did anyway, so for most implementations this just relieves them of having to document that detail.  This answer is still correct that the pointer usage may produce UB.

Quite true, @0___________.  And if a difference between the pointer sizes causes the other members to be out of register between the two definitions then that opens the doors to a whole other range of misbehaviors.

@JohnBollinger and @0___________ : I'm confused about the "no UB here" vs the "UB" comments - is the first comment meant for the initialization ONLY, and should the "UB" comment be moved up above the call to untyped_zero_first?

@JohannGerell no -assumong untyped_zero_first uses memset. But if you loop there using longs by the original pointer was double - then it is UB. THere is no concrete answer and my advice is to avoid "punning" unless you understand very well what is going on there.

@0___________: Tnx, I hear you - that's why I ask the questions, I want to understand very well what the standard promises. Still... "But if you loop there using longs by the original pointer was double - then it is UB" ... What about looping using the item_size member and casting data to (char*) ?

@JohannGerell read last bullet in point 2 of my answer

@0___________: yes, and the i:th stored value is accessed (written to) with memset (or memcpy) and dest address (char*)data + i * item_size so I wonder if that is bad (while the memset in the OP example seems ok, as written there)...

@JohannGerell i do not see (char*)data + i * item_size in your code. What are you talking about?
